# Typescript syntax for Set of Strings similar to string[]?

Tags: typescript, set

In [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/static/TypeScript%20Interfaces-34f1ad12132fb463bd1dfe5b85c5b2e6.png), you can define an Array of Strings as `string[]` or `Array<string>`. My team prefers the more succinct `string[]`.

When defining a Set of Strings, is there also a more succinct way similar to `string[]`? Or, is the only option the more verbose `Set<string>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No shorthand syntax exists for `Set`s like there are are for `Array`s. The only option is `Set<MyTypeHere>`.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find one but its good to get confirmation that I wasn't missing anything.